# Microsoft Excel: Writing a function to pass through a value and ALSO change the background color of a cell fails

Tags: excel, vba, function, cell, background-color

```
Public Function Ecell(value As Double) As Double
    Ecell = value
    'Call xtest
End Function
Public Sub xtest()
        Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 11
End Sub
```

If I use the function Ecell in a cell and give it a value - with the call to xtest commented out - it works fine. The value is just moved into the cell.

If I call the subroutine xtest on its own, it works fine. The color in cell A1 is correctly set.

If I uncomment the call to xtest in the function and use the function I get a VALUE error "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type".

Any idea why? Anyone know a workaround?

I tried many combinations of function call and setting the color in the cell. These two routines indicate the problem in the simplest way.

Comment: [Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1)

Comment: Ah... ok then. Thanks.  I guess that explains it - if not give me a solution! Hmmm... wonder if I can trigger a timer....

Comment: Answer: no you can't trigger a timer either

Comment: You could use the Ecell function to change the value and have conditional formatting on the cell to change the colour.

Comment: Thanks Darren, but answer below. Conditional formatting wouldn't have worked for my ultimate use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where this is going, but you can try using the `Calculate` event. When you call your function, you set the value of the public variable, and the procedure is executed by the `Calculate` event.
Put this code in a standard module:

```
Public flag As Long
Public Function Ecell(value As Double) As Double
    Ecell = value
    flag = 1
    ' Call xtest
End Function
Public Sub xtest()
    Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 11
End Sub

Public Function Fcell(value As Double) As Double
    Fcell = value
    flag = 0
    ' Call ztest
End Function
Public Sub ztest()
    Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End Sub
```

And in the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Select Case flag
      Case 1: Call xtest
      Case 0: Call ztest
   End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had to also save the calling address but this allowed me to use IFERROR(p1,p2) for stock prices where the first argument was a current price which could generate an error. Second argument was last close price. This way I could have the spreadsheet work without error but i needed to know if the error condition was in play. Hence the color.